# Нужна функция, перезаписывающая файл с помощью удаления указанной строки

Tags: c

На вход поступает число, которое указывает на номер строки файла. Вот эту строку нужно удалить. Т.е. перезаписать.
Вот собственно код. Необходимо добавить функцию, удаляющую строку.Ну или без нее.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 150
#define AVER 40
#define MIN 10
struct GD
{
    //ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ СТРУКТУРЫ
    char data_0[MIN];//---------дата отправки------ 
    char time_A[MIN];//---------время отправки-----
    char A[AVER];//---------------место отправки-----
    char data_1[MIN];//---------дата прибытия------
    char time_B[MIN];//---------время прибытия-----
    char B[AVER];//---------------место прибытия-----
    int N_B[MIN];//--------------количество билетов-
    double price[MIN];//---------стоимость билета---
};
void N1_READ(void), N2_WRITE(void), N3_DELETE(void), REMOVE(void);
int MENU_select(void);
int main()
{
    system("color 2");
    system("chcp 1251");//ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int y = 1;//счетчики
    char tab2[10] = "yes";//для сравнения
    char tab3[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    while (y)
    {
        switch (MENU_select())
        {
        case 1:N2_WRITE(); break;//-------------------------------------------------------------------ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ В СПИСОК
        case 2:N1_READ(); break;//------------------------------------------------------------------------ПРОСМОТР СПИСКА
        case 3:N3_DELETE(); break;//-------------------------------------------------------------------УДАЛЕНИЕ ИЗ СПИСКА
        case 4:exit(0); break;
        }
    }
}
//========================================МЕНЮ
int MENU_select()//========================================МЕНЮ
{
        int c;
        char s[80];
        system("cls");//МЕНЮ
        printf("|===========MENU===========|\n");
        printf("|1|===Добавление  списка===|\n");
        printf("|2|====Просмотр  списка====|\n");
        printf("|3|===Удаление из списка===|\n");
        printf("|4|===Выход из программы===|\n");
        printf("|==========================|\n");
        printf("|=Выберите номер  варианта=|\n");
        printf("|==========================|\n");
        s[79] = '\0';
        do
        {
            printf("Вариант: ");
            gets_s(s,80);
            c = atoi(s);
        } while (c < 0 || c>5);
        return c;
}
//======================================ЧТЕНИЕ
void N1_READ(void)
{
    FILE* file;
    char tab1[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    char str[MAX];
    int j = 0,p=0;
    while (j == 0)
    {
        file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");//Изменить значение
        system("cls");
        printf("Данные:\n");
        printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+\n");
        printf(" № |     Откуда    |      Куда     | Дата и время отправления |   Дата и время прибытия  | Билетов |   Цена  |\n");
        printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+\n");
        while (fgets(str, MAX, file))//Вывод из файла                                                                                   
        {
            p++;
            printf(" %d ", p);
            printf("%s", str);
            printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+\n");
        }
        fclose(file);
        p = 0;
        printf("Выйти?(yes): ");//---Выход из просмотра
        scanf_s("%s", tab1, 10);
        if (*tab1 == *tabk)
        {
            j = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
//======================================ЗАПИСЬ
void N2_WRITE(void)
{
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    char tab2[10] = "yes";//для сравнения
    struct GD otv[MIN];//ЖД 
    int t = 0,f=0,k=0;
    FILE* file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");
    for (int i = t; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        system("cls");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите точку отбытия: ");//-----A[MAX]-точка А
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].A, AVER);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].A);
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите точку прибытия: ");//--------B[MAX]-точка Б
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].B, AVER);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].B);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите дату отбытия: ");//------data_0-дата отправления
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].data_0, 15);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].data_0);
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите время отбытия: ");//-----time_A-время А
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].time_A, MIN);
        fprintf(file, "|%10s", otv[i].time_A);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите дату прибытия: ");//---------data_1-дата отправления
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].data_1, 15);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].data_1);
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите время прибытия: ");//-------time_B-время Б
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].time_B, MIN);
        fprintf(file, "|%10s", otv[i].time_B);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите количество билетов: ");//----N_B-количество билетов
        scanf_s("%d", otv[i].N_B);
        fprintf(file, "|%9d", *otv[i].N_B);
        fprintf(stdout, "Стоимость билета: ");//--------------price-стоимость
        scanf_s("%lf", otv[i].price);
        fprintf(file, "|%9.2lf|\n", *otv[i].price);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("продолжить ввод?(yes для продолжения/no для завершения)\n");
        scanf_s("%s", tab2, 10);//скан ответа
        if (*tabk != *tab2)//не yes/конец
        {
            i = 149;
            k++;
            t++;
            system("cls");
        }
        if (*tabk == *tab2)//yes
        {
            k++;
            t++;
        }

    }
    fclose(file);
}
//====================================УДАЛЕНИЕ
void N3_DELETE(void)
{
    char tab3[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    system("cls");
    printf("1-удаление файла\n");
    printf("2-Удаление строки в списке\n");
    printf("3-Выход\n");
    int o;
    printf("Выбор: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &o);
    switch (o)
    {
    case 1:REMOVE(); break;//Удаление файла
    case 2:break;//Удаление строки
    case 3:break;//Отмена
    }
}
//====================================УДАЛЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА
void REMOVE(void)   
{
    int m = 0;
    char tab3[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    system("cls");
    printf("Очистить файл?(yes/no): ");
    scanf_s("%s", tab3, 10);
    if (*tab3 == *tabk)
    {
        system("cls");
        if (remove("data.txt") == EOF)
        {
            printf("Ошибка, файл не очищен!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Файл успешно удален!\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
//====================================УДАЛЕНИЕ СТРОК
void DELETE()
{

}
```

Буду рад даже ссылке на пояснение.

Comment: Вы точно понимаете как происходит удаление строки в файле на blk устройстве?

Comment: В этом и суть, я не знаю как это работает

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496192/deleting-a-string-from-a-particular-position-in-a-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language

Comment: Как я понял,создается временный файл,куда перезаписывается все выше и ниже указанной мною строки.А потом идет подмена моего файла на временный.Правильно понял?